# Retrieve list access from list data

Tags: r, list, variables, shiny, lookup

If I have the following:

```
variableList <- list("a" = "alpha",
                     "b" = "beta")
```

I get that i can user variableList$a to get "alpha", but is there any way to do the reverse? How would I get "a" if I only had "alpha"? I trued variableList$'alpha' but that does not work

Comment: `names(which(variableList == 'alpha'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names(variableList)[variableList == 'alpha']
```